# Does iOS have a file name limit?

Tags: ios, expo

In expo I am attempting to a FileSystem.copyAsync and I am getting an error.  However, it's not telling me what the error is.

> File 'file:///Users/trajano/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99D624D1-2DDC-425B-97EF-E62462C21BE3/data/Containers/Data/Application/02E90AEF-EB5C-4BE9-B421-6C28D8A87EB5/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540trajano%252Fcom-devhaus-mobile/studentDay-SDdpVnp1SFJXbkUlM0Q-ZFpQdWU3T3FzSEUlM0Q.json' could not be copied to 'file:///Users/trajano/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99D624D1-2DDC-425B-97EF-E62462C21BE3/data/Containers/Data/Application/02E90AEF-EB5C-4BE9-B421-6C28D8A87EB5/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540trajano%252Fcom-devhaus-mobile/cache/eAENwtEOgiAUAFB_xnfFaj0nCmoMUDHXWwo3C9ccGdXf19nZ7EU8Kf9yultbYHXFTOXRGEkueHlN4JlKejSCfFR0JgP07QqZ2Tl0qbf25CiDQ1bYbyp4EaJcjxSwv8NE3mGC_wO4zSZosF66xxI3edkPVs0skj8r6yaZ.json'.

I count it to be a little over 423 characters for the destination.

This is an error within the simulator, I haven't tried it on a real device yet.  But even if it does work, I would still like to know WHY it didn't work.

Comment: It is MacOS path not iOS, right?

Comment: It's iOS specifically in a simulator

Comment: The underlying file system on the simulator is the macOS file system; don't trust the simulator if you want to know what iOS will do, because there are differences. As just one example, apps running on the simulator often don't exhibit case sensitivity in file names (depending on how the disk was set up), but file names are always case sensitive on iOS. That leads to a lot of "why does my app work on simulator but not on device?" questions.

Comment: Closing this off... I'll put my answer anyway, if any mod wants to re-open feel free to do so.

Comment: 1023 bytes for the complete path, and 255 bytes for each path component. Pats are in UTF8, so you can reach that limit with a relatively small number of emoji characters :-)

Answer (score 2):

It was a bit hard to debug, but eventually I was able to trace to to a missing directory in the path, but I still couldn't make Expo tell me that is what is wrong on the logs.